# Set SQL value based another value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to add to the first value `checkin` and to the last value `checkout` based on the same location and the same date.

I run this query:

```
 select USERID , CHECKTIME , SENSORID 
 from CHECKINOUT
 where USERID = 15
```

What I mean is:

```
USERID  CHECKTIME           SENSORID 
------------------------------------
15  2014-10-20 01:22:01.000 100
15  2014-10-20 12:38:22.000 100
15  2014-10-20 22:00:54.000 100
15  2014-10-21 01:24:30.000 100
15  2014-10-21 07:31:39.000 100
15  2014-10-21 22:11:47.000 100
15  2014-10-22 00:10:34.000 100
15  2014-10-22 05:51:47.000 100
```

to be :

```
USERID  CHECKTIME                   SENSORID 
---------------------------------------------
15  2014-10-20 01:22:01.000-checkin     100
15  2014-10-20 12:38:22.000-checkout    100
15  2014-10-20 22:00:54.000-checkin     100
15  2014-10-21 01:24:30.000-checkin     100
15  2014-10-21 07:31:39.000-checkout    100
15  2014-10-21 22:11:47.000-checkin     100
15  2014-10-22 00:10:34.000-checkin     100
15  2014-10-22 05:51:47.000-checkout    100
```

But based on `sensorid` be the same and the same date.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Could you please explain better what you want ?

Comment: where is the location field?

Comment: location field is SENSORID .

Comment: im new user @ MS SQL what i need is mark check in or check out but if its need to have new column to insert in it i can create one

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
select USERID,CHECKTIME + case when code % 2 =0 then '- Check out' 
else ' -Check IN' end,SENSORID from (
 select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY USERID,CHECKTIME 
                          order by USERID ,CHECKTIME) code 
from table1) as t1
```

Comment: its gave me error "Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
"

Comment: OK, you got an error. The error message tells you there is a problem with type conversion. Did you try anything to get it to work? The answer is solid and should work to give you what you seem to want. But there may be some wrinkles to iron out in your particular instance. Change something, anything, to see if you can -- oh, I dunno -- perhaps find the problem yourself. Here's a hint. The solution doesn't do any date manipulation. So the date is in your data. So if `checktime` is a datetime field, you can't concatenate strings to it. So perhaps settle for a generated field beside it.

Answer (score 0):

try this, this can help you :

```
select userid,convert(varchar(30),checktime,121) +
       case when 
       ((row_number() over (partition by userid,sensorid,convert(varchar(30),checktime,101)
                            order by checktime))%2 = 0) 
        then '-checkout' 
        else '-checkin' end
        as checktime,sensorid
from temt
where userid = 15
```

[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3ca1/2) is demo sql fiddle

here is the solution if you want to add a new column with values :

```
alter table temt 
add   checkinorout varchar(50) 
;with cte_update (userid,checkinorout,ctime,sensorid) as
(
  select userid,checkinorout,convert(varchar(30),checktime,121) +
         case when 
         ((row_number() over (partition by userid,sensorid,convert(varchar(30),checktime,101)
                              order by checktime))%2 = 0) 
          then '-checkout' 
          else '-checkin' end
  as ctime,sensorid
  from temt
)
update cte_update set checkinorout = ctime 


select * from temt
```

[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae440/1) is demo sql fiddle.

Comment: firest thankes for your answer :) its working but when i tray to  "select USERID , CHECKTIME , SENSORID from CHECKINOUT order by CHECKTIME  "             its gave me the normal statement i need when i select this normal statment i found the table as you answered me

Comment: so you want desired result with simple select statement. correct?

Comment: yes MR user2315555 or you can say i want to edit the column checktime to be date-time-checkin or date-time-checkout sorry i m new @ SQL

Comment: I don't know why you have such requirement but to achieve this, 1. you have to change the data type of your column if it is not varchar type. 2. update that column like update checktime = convert(varchar(30),checktime,121) +
       case when 
       ((row_number() over (partition by userid,sensorid,convert(varchar(30),checktime,101)
                            order by checktime))%2 = 0); personally, I won't recommend this because if this table is filled from application code then it would break all things.

Comment: MR  user2315555 you are right what about create anew column and column name checkinorout and insert the check in or out in it ? i know sorry about allot of my ask .